# Processing Movie background change

Tags: processing, leap-motion

I had another question about processing and a project i'm making. I would like to play a movie in a loop on the background. I managed to do this by initializing a Movie and putting it in an image the size of my app. But now I would like to load in multiple movies and add a button to change the background when pressed with the leap motion. Is this possible ? Or should I use a different library for this ?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

DarthSwedo

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You'll have much better luck if you **just try something** and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

That being said, I'm going to try to clear up some of the general confusion you seem to have.

**Step 1:** You need to figure out what library or libraries you're using. In all of your questions, you seem to not be sure which library you're using. Which Leap Motion library are you using? How did you set it up? Where is its documentation? You say you're using a `Movie` class. Where is that coming from? Are you sure it's not from the [Video library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/index.html)?

If you have more specific questions in the future, **please** provide this information. We can't really help you without it. But more importantly, **you** need to know the answers to these questions if any of this is ever going to make any sense.

**Step 2:** Read the documentation for those libraries. Processing comes with [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/). The Video library comes with [its own documentation page](https://processing.org/reference/). I'm sure whatever Leap Motion library you're using has something similar. You need to read about the functions available to you. That's a huge part of programming. Right now your question is just asking whether something possible, and the honest answer to that is, well, what happened when you googled it?

**Step 3**: Try something. After you read through the documentation, just **try something**. Write some code based on the examples in the documentation. Even if that code doesn't work, that's okay, because then you can use it as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a more specific question.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kevin, you've been really helpful ! I'll try some things now and if I get stuck i'll just post the entire problem. I get your point. I'm using LeapMotionP5 library, all the other things are libraries from processing itself like the video library and minim audioplayer.